# Why is Console App taking so long to start up

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a console application that I am using with Autofac. When I first started working on the code - things moved pretty quickly - Now, for some reason its taking 6 + minutes to just start the application. Basically 6 minutes or more to resolve all the dependencies and start the program.

This is how I set up the program....

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = ContainerConfig.Configure();
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var app = scope.Resolve<IApplication>();

            app.Run(args);
        }
    }
```

Here is the ContainterConfig Class....

```
public static class ContainerConfig
{
    public static IContainer Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<Application>().As<IApplication>();

        builder.RegisterType<AcmeEngineRepositoryBase>().As<IAcmeEngineRepositoryBase>();
        builder.RegisterType<AuditLogicBase>().As<IAuditLogicBase>();
        builder.RegisterType<AuditRepositoryBase>().As<IAuditRepositoryBase>();
        builder.RegisterType<AuditLogic>().As<IAuditLogic>();
        builder.RegisterType<AuditRepository>().As<IAuditRepository>();


        builder.RegisterType<BirdieLogic>().As<IBirdieLogic>();
        builder.RegisterType<BirdieRepository>().As<IBirdieRepository>();

        builder.RegisterType<AttackLogic>().As<IAttackLogic>();
        builder.RegisterType<AttackRepository>().As<IAttackRepository>();

        builder.RegisterType<SettingsLogic>().As<ISettingsLogic>();
        builder.RegisterType<SettingsRepository>().As<ISettingsRepository>();

        builder.RegisterType<AcmeEngineLogic>().As<IAcmeEngineLogic>();
        builder.RegisterType<AcmeEngineRepository>().As<IAcmeEngineRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<AcmeEngineApiRepository>().As<IAcmeEngineApiRepository>();

        builder.RegisterType<ExperianLogic>().As<IExperianLogic>();
        builder.RegisterType<ExperianRepository>().As<IExperianRepository>();



        builder.RegisterType<ValidationLogic>().As<IValidationLogic>();

        builder.Register(c => new MatchStat()).As<MatchStat>().SingleInstance();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Then, I have a

```
public void Run(string[] args)
{
    Application Code Here
}
```

When I first started there was no issues, now as I have added a few items its seems to be getting worse.  I assume that I have some issue with my IOC containers but I have read thru a lot of documentation and nothing seems to point to my issue that I have been able to find.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is it taking a long time to start it directly or during a debugging session?

Comment: That's it!  Thank you - Been working on this a while and did not think to try in release mode - once I did that and disabled JustMycode - It ran like wildfire again.  Wish I know why debug was so dang slow tho.  Thanks you

Comment: I had that happen once and I had to completely remove and re-install Visual Studio. After that, it worked just fine even when debugging.

Comment: I will give that a shot - While release is great -I still got some work left on it.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Look in VS output window during startup. I bet it's busy loading symbols. That's always pretty slow.